# My side nav is still visible to the right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a side nav for mobile view, the nav slides in whenever the hamburger icon is clicked, the problem is that when the nav is hidden, it is still visible when you scroll to right, i tried overflow hidden but nothing worked.

I tried to hide the nav by moving it 100% to the left, and it slides in with left 0.

The other problem is that the content below the nav is scrolablle and you can leave the nav to move down.

i tried to simplify the css as possile.

[image]

Here is my code :

```js
document.querySelector('.hamburger').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.side-nav').classList.toggle('is-open');
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 2000px;
}

header {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.hamburger {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger span {
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 10px;
}

.hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 20px;
}

.side-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
  height: calc(100vh - 65px);
  transition: left .15s;
}

.is-open {
  left: 0;
  transition: left .15s;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="hamburger">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <nav class="side-nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>More</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `overflow: hidden` to a parent to hide the elements, which are outside of the sections. The best is to add `.wrapper` container to wrap all your elements inside `body` tag and add `overflow: hidden` to it. (You can try to add it to `body`, but I do not suggest this).

Also, do not transition `left` as this will reduce the performance of your app/website. Use `transform: translateX(100%);` instead to move it 100% to the left and back to 0% when it `.is-open` class is added. [This is a good article to read](https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108) about CSS transitions.

So with some tweaks, it will look something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('.hamburger').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.side-nav').classList.toggle('is-open');
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 2000px;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.hamburger {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger span {
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 10px;
}

.hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 20px;
}

.side-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
  height: calc(100vh - 65px);
  transition: transform .15s;
}

.is-open {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div class="hamburger">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <nav class="side-nav">
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>More</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: The solution worked only when I added overflow:hidden to body , it didn't work with the wrapper div i created,

Comment: It didn't work, because you have to set a relative position to a parent of the `side-nav` (in this case `header`).